# Are complete metric spaces of finite Hausdorff dimension locally compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is every complete metric $(M,d)$ of Hausdorff dimension $n<\infty$ a locally compact space?

More generally, given a complete metric space of finite Hausdorff dimension, can we always find a locally identical metric $d'$ on $M$ so that $(M,d')$ has the Heine-Borel property, i.e. so that every bounded and closed subset is compact?

Comment: you probably need finite Hausdorff measure (not only finite dimension), in order to get local total boundedness, but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $M=\left\{v\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, v_x=0\lor \exists q\in\Bbb Q, v_y=qv_x\right\}$ with the metric $$d(a,b)=\begin{cases}\lVert a\rVert+\lVert b\rVert&\text{if }a,b\text{ linearly independent}\\ \lVert a-b\rVert&\text{if }a,b\text{ linearly dependent}\end{cases}$$ It's a connected complete metric space, and the origin has no compact neighbourhood. However, it is countable union of subspaces which are isometric to $\Bbb R$, and therefore its Hausdorff dimension is $1$.

Comment: Thank you! So some kind of hedgehog space does the job as a counter example. Should it be $v_x\neq 0$?

Comment: @Christian Nope, I want that $(0,0)$ point in there!

Comment: But then there is a problem with the condition $v_y/v_x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Christian There might be a semantical subtlety on whether $f(x)\in A$ is hypothetical (i.e. that if $x$ is in the domain of $f$, then $f(x)\in A$) or whether it's a restrictive statement ($x$ is in the domain of $f$ and $f(x)\in A$). Personally, I see it as the latter, and I don't think the other interpretation, if used at all, is practical for humans. Perhaps I can imagine machines being forced into the former, I guess. However, I changed the notation.

Comment: Thank you! I fully agree and would have been fine with the original statement as well. My objection above was based on misreading a part of the condition and writing before thinking.